# Time is not displaying in the Top Bar

Tags: unity, panel, time

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with dual boot along side Windows 8.

The top panel or bar doesn't display the time.

When I open the Clock menu, all the settings over there are grayed out
**Settings > Time and date > Clock**

I tried other methods (like `dconf`) but that didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean with "greyed out". Please, take a screen shoot!

Comment: I have precisely the same issue. "Grayed out" means that none of the options / check boxes in the Clock tab are responsive.

Comment: Having same issue and reinstalling Gnome-control-center and restarting lightdm don't fix it for me...

Comment: found answer here http://www.maketecheasier.com/date-time-missing-ubuntu-1310/

Answer (score 169):

> 1. Reinstall `indicator-datetime`. It should be installed by default, but just in case you have removed it unknowingly, it is best to run the install command again.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
>    ```
> 2. Next, we are going to reconfigure the date time:
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
>    ```
> 3. Lastly, restart unity.
>
>    ```
>    sudo killall unity-panel-service
>    ```
>
> That’s it. The date and time indicator will appear in the menu bar now.

([Source](http://www.maketecheasier.com/date-time-missing-ubuntu-1310/))

Comment: Worked for me and I didn't lose my session, thanks.

Comment: Just doing step 3 worked for me (you could try it first, and if it doesn't help perform the other steps):
sudo killall unity-panel-service

Comment: I just needed to kill unity-panel-service in order to work for me.

Comment: perfect!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 81):

For me, it was enough to restart unity:

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: yes, that's it...

Comment: Work like a charm .....

Answer (score 19):

**WARNING:** All users will logout immediately, possibly losing data. **All applications will also close**.

It is happening to me sometimes, the solution is:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this will logout all users immediately, possibly losing data.

Comment: Indeed, this is an annoying solution, but alas, it is a solution.

Comment: @minerz029 I have edited the answer to include your comment as it is an important information for people trying out the above command.

Comment: There is a better solution mentioned: i.e: sudo killall unity-panel-service

Comment: I've managed to also get the bug in Ubuntu 14.04. Happens from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

I've been in the same situation myself once. What I've made was to reinstall `gnome-control-center` using the following commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

After I restart the GUI from tty1 uing the following command:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

the problem didn't appeared again until now.

Answer (score 0):

It means your chosen region is not matched to your local server.

To correct:
1/ set the time&date to your actual region (eg China)
2/ use synaptic to select the repository server for your actual region (eg China).
3/ reboot.

This should solve the issue.  Recurrence may be caused by change in location, or change in server, or update/upgrade.  If so, repeat the above.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply restart your computer. Time will show itself on the top panel again. I have also faced this problem a few times.

Because sometimes 
sudo lightdm restart won't work