# Can I modify the indicators?

Tags: 14.04

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, sometimes one of the indicators disapears, never to be seen again (so far I've lost the network connection and the date & time icons). Is there a way to edit these? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this command, if you run Unity, as it will restart Unity:

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

was found in this forum, [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366350/time-is-not-displaying-in-the-top-bar/)

Comment: It worked, thanks! Restored date & time, but not the network connection icon.  I searched in Settings>Network but there doesn't seem to be an option to show in the menu bar like there is for the clock

Comment: Btw a 'dock' is not the top bar, i think a dock is meant to describe [this](http://tr1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2015/05/07/34d363c7-f4ad-11e4-940f-14feb5cc3d2a/screenshot-from-2013-06-16-103749.png) (bottom bar). the top bar could be called status bar or top bar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general tool to configure the indicators. Each indicator is shown if it is installed. Some indicators can be hidden via configuration, e.g. the bluetooth settings have an option "Show Bluetooth status in the menu bar" which can hide it.

If your network indicator is not showing then either there is a bug in the network indicator (which is why `killall unity-panel-service` may restart it) or you have uninstalled the package that provides it (`network-manager-gnome`).