# Date and time not showing up in Ubuntu 14.04 even though the option is ticked in settings

Tags: 14.04

I am not seeing the date/time show up in the top panel after recently upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. The option under Date and Time in the Settings page is already ticked, but it doesn't seem to be taking effect. Please help since I would quite like that back.

Answer (score 2):

This will make the date and time indicator appear in the menu bar now.

> 1. Reinstall indicator-datetime. It should be installed by default, but just in case you have removed it unknowingly, it is best to run the install command again.
>
> `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime`
>
> 2. Next, we are going to reconfigure the date time:
>
> `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata`
>
> 3. Lastly, restart unity.
>
> `sudo killall unity-panel-service`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366350/time-is-not-displaying-in-the-top-bar)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it didn't work.. in the other thread, he says the settings are grayed out. For me, they aren't grayed out, I can change them. But having the "Show a clock in the menu bar" option ticked doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't help. How about try this.  `dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/`

Comment: I got the following message  "error: The connection is closed

Usage:
  dconf reset [-f] PATH 

Reset a key or dir.  -f is required for dirs.

Arguments:
  PATH        Either a KEY or DIR
  KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
  DIR         A directory path (starting and ending with '/')"