# Ubuntu 22.04 Unity: clock in top bar flickers a few times before dissapearing completely upon login

Tags: unity, 22.04, clock, top-bar

Basically the post

[Time is not displaying in the Top Bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366350/time-is-not-displaying-in-the-top-bar)

(grayed-out clock settings as well) but the solutions from that post do not work for me, perhaps due to being Ubuntu 22.04.

Any suggestions how to make my clock appear again?

EDIT: It magically reappeared again. I am not aware of anything special I did to do so but it's been showing for two days now. However, whenever I click it, to say look at the calendar that pops up, it opens as expected but then closes after 2 seconds and the clock disappears for half a second before reappearing. Strange behaviour!

Comment: Ubuntu Unity was still a *respin* for 22.04; it didn't became an official flavor until Ubuntu Unity 22.10 (which is now EOL).   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2022-August/002669.html  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue751#Ubuntu_Unity_as_an_official_flavor  If you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and added the Unity desktop yourself, that is on-topic, but *Ubuntu Unity 22.04 LTS* was still a respin & included 3rd party packages (replacing Ubuntu packages)

Comment: @guiverc I am sure I have Ubuntu 22.04, but I can select different desktop environments upon logging in, of which I use Unity (default). Are you saying I should change something in my post...?